# ValueError at /checkout/ The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing

Tags: python, django

*ValueError at /checkout/
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:

The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.*

**Error Screenshot**

- [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA4Bm.png)
- [This line is causing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czGXC.png)

**APP views.py Checkout**

```
@login_required
def checkout(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        name = request.user
        print(name)
        order=Orders(customerID=name)
        order.save()
        cart = Cart(request)
        for items in cart:
            print(items)
            OrderDetails(orderID=order,productID=items['product'],quantity=items['quantity'],price=items['total_price']).save()
        order = Orders.objects.filter(customerID=name)
        OrderDetail = OrderDetails.objects.filter(orderID=order)
        customerDetails = Customer.objects.filter(user=name).count()
        print(customerDetails)
        return render(request, 'app/checkout.html',{'orders':OrderDetail,'address':customerDetails})
```

**CheckOut Template**

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Buy Now{% endblock title %}
{% block main-content %}
<div class="container">
 <div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h4>Order Summary</h4>
    <hr>
    {% for order in orders %}
      <div class="card mb-2">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5>{{order.name}}</h5>
          <p>Quantity: {{order.quantity}}</p>
          <p class="fw-bold">Price: {{order.price}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %} 
    <small>Term and Condition: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, ullam saepe! Iure optio repellat dolor velit, minus rem. Facilis cumque neque numquam laboriosam, accusantium adipisci nisi nihil in et quis?</small>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-1">
    <h4>Shipping Address</h4>
    <hr>
    {% for ad in address %}
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h5>{{ad.name}}</h5>
        <p>{{ad.address}}</p>
        <p>{{ad.phone}}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
        <div class="form-check mt-2 mb-5">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="">
          <label class="form-check-label fw-bold" for="">
           </label>
        </div>
        <form action="{% url 'app:buy-now' %}">
        <div class="text-end">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning mt-3 px-5 fw-bold">Continue</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock main-content %)
```

**APP Urls.py**

```
from re import template
from django.urls import path
from app import views

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from.forms import LoginForm, MyPasswordChangeForm

app_name='app'

urlpatterns = [
    # path('', views.home),
    path('',views.ProductView,name='home'),
    path('product-detail/<int:pk>', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
    path('showcart/',views.show_cart,name='showcart'),
    path('Fruits/', views.Fruits, name='Fruits'),
    path('Fruits/<slug:data>', views.Fruits, name='FruitsData'),
    path('Dried/', views.Dried, name='Dried'),
    path('Dried/<slug:data>', views.Dried, name='DriedData'),
    path('Vegetables/', views.Vegetables, name='Vegetables'),
    path('Vegetables/<slug:data>', views.Vegetables, name='VegetablesData'),
    path('profile/', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('address/', views.address, name='address'),
    path('accounts/login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='app/login.html',authentication_form=LoginForm),name='login'),
    path('passwordchange/',auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='app/passwordchange.html',form_class=MyPasswordChangeForm, success_url='/passwordchangedone/'),name='passwordchange'),
    path('passwordchangedone/',auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='app/passwordchangedone.html'),name='passwordchangedone'),
    path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='app:login'),name='logout'),
    path('registration/', views.CustomerRegistrationView.as_view(), name='customerregistration'),
   
    path('buy/', views.buy_now, name='buy-now'),

    path('orders/', views.orders, name='orders'),
    # path('changepassword/', views.change_password, name='changepassword'),
    
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
     # path('add-to-cart/', views.add_to_cart, name='add-to-cart'),

    # path('pluscart/',views.plus_cart),
    # path('minuscart/',views.minus_cart),
    # path('removecart/',views.remove_cart),


    # path('add-to-cart/<slug:data>', views.add_to_cart, name='add-to-cart_DATA'),



] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`order = Orders.objects.filter(customerID=name)`

Have to change it to:

`order = Orders.objects.latest('id')`

This error arises because the model had one to many relationship but what filter does is getting multiplte values for the customer orders.
If one customer places an order he would have one orderID but multiple products in the order. So, as order returns multiple values here so for getting products in the order we get a slicing error.
So, to resolve this I have used 'latest()' an in-built django models functions which retrieves the latest added id from the table.